# C# Is there an option to see file changes without reopening it after changed event

Tags: c#, file

Is there an option to see what exactly changed in file?

There is an event when a file was changed (in FileSystem), but it requires to open the file, save its content, open the file after it was changed, save content again, and then compare contents.

Is there a simpler and shorter way? Like an event but with a parameter that holds what exactly changed?

Comment: To monitor an event of changes to FS, you can use [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netcore-3.1). To track changes and keep its history, you may use any [VCS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) e.g. **git**.

Comment: There is no such event. Can you tell us _why_ you want such an event?

Comment: Whose code is writing these changes? Yours? Or some other process?

Comment: Come on, i am not asking how to use GIT. I am asking EXACTLY how to track changes in FILE without opening it twice

Comment: @StrangePotato You can't. It is not possible.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use the date modified tag of the file.

```
var lastModified = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime("C:\filepath\file.something");

Console.WriteLine(lastModified.ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss"));
```

You might need to to save this variable to another file then check against it.

This is probably isn't the most preferable solution.

Comment: Thanks, but as i said opening file 2 times not the best solution

Comment: FYI: Using my code won't open the original file you are talking about. It will just check its tag.